# Java add subtype instance to a collection of supertype?

Tags: java, generics

The following code compiles and runs without problem:

```
class Solution {
    public  List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        Set<List<Integer>> res  = new HashSet<>();
        if(nums.length==0) return new ArrayList<>(res);
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length-2;i++){
            int j =i+1;
           int  k = nums.length-1;
            while(j<k){
                int sum = nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k];
                if(sum==0)res.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i],nums[j++],nums[k--]));
                else if ( sum >0) k--;
                else if (sum<0) j++;
            }

        }
        return new ArrayList<>(res);
    }
}
```

I'm baffled with this line of code

```
res.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i],nums[j++],nums[k--]))
```

`res` is of type `HashSet<List<Integer>>`, and `Arrays.asList` returns value of type `ArrayList` (not `java.util.ArrayList`, but an internally defined class according to java 8 [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java), which also implements `java.util.List`)

Why ***DOESN'T*** adding `ArrayList` instance to a collection of `List` raise exception?

Although the former is subtype of latter, as far as I know the adding operation should not be allowed because `HashSet<ArrayList>` is not subtype of `Set<List>`?

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>` **is a** `List<Integer>`. The trick is often related to type arguments, not to the base types themselves :-)

Comment: Hi please check my updated content, thx!

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns `List<T>`, and internally `ArrayList`.

Comment: From the [JavaDocs of `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): All Implemented Interfaces: Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, **Set<E>**. So yes, `HashSet` is not a subtype of `Set` because a `Set` is an `interface`, but `HashSet` implements it.

Comment: As @ernest_k said: An `ArrayList<Integer>` is a `List<Integer>`. That's all that matters, here. I think you already got this, it's just that your last thought about a `HashSet...` not being a subtype of `Set...` is irrelevant. You are adding a `List<Integer>` to a `HashSet<List<Integer>>` - there's nothing wrong about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Are%20different%20concrete%20instantiations%20of%20the%20same%20parameterized%20type%20compatible?) on the compatibility you're questioning:

> A `List<Object>` is compatible to a `Collection<Object>` because the two types are instantiations of a generic supertype and its generic subtype and the instantiations are for the same type argument Object.

The types that are incompatible are those (related ones) that have different type arguments (event if those argument types are otherwise related/compatible) - same source:

> A `ArrayList<String>` object cannot be passed as argument to a method that asks for a `ArrayList<Object>` because the two types are instantiations of the same generic type, but for different type arguments, and for this reason they are not compatible with each other.

This:

- `Arrays.asList(nums[i],nums[j++],nums[k--]) //creating and adding List<Integer>`

Is doing an instantiation of the first kind above.

---

> Although the former is subtype of latter, as far as I know the adding operation should not be allowed because `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>` is not subtype of `Set<List<Integer>>`

You have one wrong fact here. The static return type of `Arrays.asList(nums[i],nums[j++],nums[k--])` is *not* `ArrayList<Integer>`. It's `List<Integer>`. You have good insight into the runtime class returned by `asList`, but the compiler does not care about that (except when validating that code itself), it stops at the static type (the declared return type) of `asList`, which in this case is `List<Integer>`.

It's true that `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>` is not compatible with `Set<List<Integer>>`, but this is irrelevant because the compiler is not looking at the actual runtime class (even if this is what you use to instantiate the set).

As far as I can see, all that the compiler needs to enforce here is that you're calling `Set<List<Integer>>.add()` with an argument that is a `List<Integer>`, which you are doing.